# How can I make my 2d app/game fit or scale with all android and iPhone devices?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, screen, scale

I have an app that has normal button on the corners and some in the mid-down and  something like a frame covering the buttons.

When I go to Game then change game to simulator and change the device scene(for example iPhone 12), some of the buttons go out of the screen, some of them do not stay in the same position. When I change it to another device screen like "Samsung Galaxy J7" most of the buttons are in the right position but in other devices it is not. I have tried to see YouTube videos and downloaded some scripts but it did not work for me, I tried to use anchors but I could not really understand how to do it.

I am not sure if it is in Unity Player Settings because I checked most of it and I could not find but if it is there please tell.

Answer (score 1):

Editing your Canvas Components [(my settings)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdnp1.png) might help : https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html

- Make sure your [Canvas Render Mode: Screen Space Camera](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UICanvas.html) then attach your camera.
- Set the UI [Scale mode: Scale with Screen Size.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html#:%7E:text=Scaling%20with%20Screen%20Size&text=It%20is%20also%20added%20by,resolution%20to%20use%20as%20reference.)
- Set your [Button Anchors](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UIBasicLayout.html) according to your needs.

Comment: my canvas render mode is screen space camera                                                                                    the UI scale mode is scale with screen size                                                                                               i have tried to change the anchors but nothing is working                                                                     is there any script or a video that does make the app/game fit into any screen